# Transform array of types into functions parameters types in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, eventemitter

I have a custom Event Emitter system in typescript, but I can only use 1 parameter, there is the code :

```js
type EventMap = Record<string, any>;

type EventKey<T extends EventMap> = string & keyof T;
type EventReceiver<T> = (params: T) => void;

interface IEmitter<T extends EventMap> {
    on<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void;
    
    off<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void;
    
    emit<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, params: T[K]): void;
}


class EventHandler<T extends EventMap> implements IEmitter<T> {
    private emitter: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    
    on<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void {
        this.emitter.on(eventName, fn);
    }
    
    off<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void {
        this.emitter.off(eventName, fn);
    }
    
    emit<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, params: T[K]): void {
        this.emitter.emit(eventName, params);
    }
}

const handler = new EventHandler<{
    foo: string,
    bar: number
    multiple: [ string, number ]
}>();

handler.emit('foo', 'baz');
handler.emit('multiple', 'aaa', 10);

handler.on('foo', (param) => console.log(param)); // baz
handler.on('multiple', (param) => console.log(param)); // [ 'aaa', 10 ] => This is not what I want
```

You can see that the `multiple` event takes one parameter for the `on` method and this parameter is an array containing the two values. 
**BUT** I want to be able to do this :

```js
handler.on('multiple', (aaa, ten) => console.log(`${aaa} , ${ten}`)); // aaa , 10
```

How can I modify the code to be able to do this ?

Comment: refactor everything to use tuples instead?  `type EventReceiver<T extends readonly any[]> = (...params: T) => void;`  and then `{foo: [string], bar: [number], multiple: [string, number]}`?

Comment: or complicate `EventReceiver` to detect array types, but that might do things you don't want and could be fragile: `type EventReceiver<T> = (...params: T extends readonly any[] ? T : [T]) => void`

Comment: Also named tuples would help in 4.0: `multiple: [strarg: string, nrArgs: number]`

Comment: Okay l'll try the first solution, you're right it's better go use Tuples, thanks !

Comment: Let me know if you want those ideas written up as an answer, good luck

Comment: @jcalz Hi, your solution works, but in the `emit` method I have to put a tuple of the arguments, so it breaks my old code and it's not beautiful I think

Comment: @jcalz And the solution doesn't work, when I use it, all the parameters are an array of the arguments puts in emit, that's weird and not what I want ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I think it'll be simpler if you make an answer containing all the code (with testing).

Comment: sure, when I next get the chance

Comment: I don't know what `EventEmitter` is; is that some custom typed thing of yours?  I'm going to treat it as `any` for now and just worry about the typings of the code above

Comment: It's `import {EventEmitter} from 'events';`, `events` is a node module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my first inclination here is to turn all parameters into tuple-typed parameter lists, so a single parameter of type `string` is written as `[string]`.  The following changes could be made to your code:

```
type EventMap = Record<string, any[]>;
type EventReceiver<T extends any[]> = (...params: T) => void;

interface IEmitter<T extends EventMap> {
    on<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void;
    off<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void;
    emit<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, ...params: T[K]): void; // note
}
```

You can see that `EventMap` now requires that the values are of type `any[]`, and both `EventReceiver` and `IEmitter.emit()` use [tuples in rest/spread positions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to allow functions of multiple parameters to work.  You have to change your `EventHandler` class a little to match that:

```
class EventHandler<T extends EventMap> implements IEmitter<T> {
    private emitter: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    on<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void {
        this.emitter.on(eventName, fn as EventReceiver<any[]>);
    }

    off<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void {
        this.emitter.off(eventName, fn as EventReceiver<any[]>);
    }

    emit<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, ...params: T[K]): void {
        this.emitter.emit(eventName, ...params);
    }
}
```

(Aside: note that `EventReceiver<T[K]>` is not being seen as compatible with `(...args: any[])=>void` so I've used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions))

And now you should be able to call things the way you want:

```
const handler = new EventHandler<{
    foo: [string],
    bar: [number],
    multiple: [string, number]
}>();

handler.emit('foo', 'baz');
handler.emit('multiple', 'aaa', 10);
handler.on('foo', (param) => console.log(param));
handler.on('multiple', (aaa, ten) => console.log(`${aaa} , ${ten}`));
```

---

The alternative here would potentially be to make `EventReceiver` check to see if `T` is an array type and spread it if so, but that's clunky and unless you need it I'd be wary of trying it.  If you need to, it might use something like

```
type MaybeSpread<T> = T extends readonly any[] ? T : [T];
type EventReceiver<T> = (...params: MaybeSpread<T>) => void;
```

and then `...params: MaybeSpread<T[K]>`. I've included it in the playground link below if it matters.

---

If something about either of these solutions doesn't work for you, please elaborate... preferably by adding something to the code that demonstrates the problem.  In any case, hope that helps and good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQG4FMB2NkmDGdKOAXzgDMoIQ4BydDbAZ1oChXMBDEdJsTgMboUGKAE8YAC2CYA5gBUArmAA2vROzha4MMWGFosMANLoxAHnlx0AD0KYAJkxFGAspzAA+OAF44TGCgZWTgAMjgAazMIcjh5AG5NbV19F2x3MF84ACV0AWgHcwCguQAaOE5MMQBtAF1PRO0dPQNGGFyhYFFLazssJwqquu8-AAoAOkn+KG4mAC44gEpfb1QIYAdE1iaZQihyQWEASVx8PZ7bewHDdI9vBG2m7QhMc2Neq+cbkzNLT09RgwjAA5bjoBbGcrkTALb4ddBdIiWarGeqLBZrDaNJ5aGLkN4ffpfNqmCzyf6AtqgngQqEwtLtPII7ryFFojHrTaPHHoPAwAmXIkM0l-AFA7DU8FwSFwSbjaazBas1HouCYrlNEjsblwAQqThMYlGAASlQcaigFz6jiNty8cFAql5RmcJz553JGhxWjAQVQnEI1ndRFhbVOBCIWUw6AA7gzw3tRostt64C8BdbriTfuSxVSwbSKPS4UzEZbley1ZyvanktImONeWciOMXpSQWC6RVbYzOt1KjU0dicVqdU08RnPsKcxTxTBJYXoaGjPCy8jUZ5Veqa7WdPXG8GoK3yOR2xLO0XuwzV-2hkOx9pR6mm-z3oKbdOybP8zTpeU5QqIDzHEbJbtWDy7loUjAA2L57Ae+BnvOF4AZwMxAcmD5aFqmpJFo+SYAEcCSGaFpRrGDKmo4FrmBB3rkBAEALNUxTBLUpRYXAABGaHMZgiggFxRDsZxICKCoMDAE6zGsWUcD8YJwk6iQAKYTqJHUS2L6jLQDEQLQ5S0DxABetCYU0GnmlpfI6WJElSWoBl0JwLlOQAjAADOZ2iWRaraYDpelOaMgHLD43gEUwEBqOMKgQLIIVodwizeVovktm2tB2ZJTrBS5nDlPYYURS8UUxXFCUAAYACQIPlZDlLV9gkJVKWJKOXA8HwhxwO4YhCQAyr66CcA4Gg6ikrRGCKVjvlmbh3FkskhOEURiDEcTDs0qTfBkWQdAURSBME5QDg0eHbcIfWDcNo1-Fks2Zs4UAjQ4LwqGIgyDnAAD8cRwMx8i1Ftk3XqWLIjHAExTElQELNd6BDS9d3ksVVZYhduxEAcQhwG6zbloSH67YtdE4umb5PZ+opIQuf5Fsu2A3kiFabhyGOphOlNTt8M3fh2v4ykuYN9izbJs+jGrei+k5CrzM55gLUoyqh6HAQjSOveulbqltT7aHqBo9lRVmE3NPYZN4jpqDwzB4wmLP3JxvpdAGwhwSG8aHuRcbfA7UBJim3oU0T83YHzivnoLdKM72zJixuYEbDutbQbBh7+bTF7QleJai5aA7DKlTz6+TJ6y8T2ZfpHyHRwzIvx+W4tJ2NZOp-uHtHniWc8F2BoN2uhf3qmpdPDL3Ny1XNNznTKsw2r8OcP1iO3YUrMtynqZpwhEZHtpM8ofPsxXgOxe4bhOqRfA6XEH40a+20Js0W3TR6Qsy0camPFQAsClCVAn9vTZQclKFix05J-yUpqVSQc0qkWsohXSjEnJGU4KZYuN8d62XEjlRyhl8ruS8ltTBmUgrlESuhNGkVoroFivFChyUMHwK7gFLKOCQF5RcoVLAVDSo0LoVVWq9U4CNQQM1VqmESBAA)

Comment: Thanks you, I'll try this !